# YouTube and AdAway whitelist?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, youtube, ads, hosts

I use AdAway to modify my hosts file with quite a few aggressive sources. Unfortunately when my filters are active I can't see any channel or user pictures in the YouTube app. I can't figure out what hostname(s) I need to whitelist to fix this.

I've tried using the tcpdump log to add a bunch of Google/YouTube hostnames but this hasn't worked and I don't understand why. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally resolved this on my own. After lots of DNS logging I found the necessary. hostnames.

- s.youtube.com
- s.ytimg.com
- youtubei.googleapis.com
- yt3.ggpht.com

Comment: Which are? Others may benefit from your list...

Comment: I certainly hope so

Comment: brilliant! i had installed adaway on a rooted galaxy s3 running 4.3, and the audio on youtube videos was either gone, or sounded garbled. (youtube's ads had perfect audio) i whitelisted the 4 entries you discovered, and youtube audio is back.

Comment: It worked for YouTube Community Posts.